# Python destructor called in the "wrong" order based on reference count

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor

As far as I understand Python destructors should be called when the reference count of an object reaches 0. But this assumption seems not to be correct. Look at the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.__b = b
        print("Construct A")
        
    def __del__(self):
        # It seems that the destructor of B is called here.
        print("Delete A")
        # But it should be called here
        
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Construct B")
        
    def __del__(self):
        print("Delete B")
        
b = B()
a = A(b)
```

Outputs

```
Construct B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Construct A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Delete B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Delete A
```

But A has a reference to B, so I would expect the following output:

```
Construct B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Construct A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Delete A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Delete B
```

What am I not getting?

Comment: This is also explained in the official Python FAQ: [My class defines `__del__` but it is not called when I delete the object.](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#my-class-defines-del-but-it-is-not-called-when-i-delete-the-object). Also the documentation of [`__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) contains useful information.

Comment: "Python destructors should be called when the reference count of an object reaches 0" – reference counting is purely an implementation of CPython. It is not even the only reachability mechanism there, as the garbage collector takes care of cyclic references. Relying on ``__del__`` being called at a specific point is likely wrong, no matter what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, since the objects are still alive when the interpreter shuts down, you are actually not even guaranteed that `__del__` will be called. At this point, the language makes no guarantees about when the finalizer is called.

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects
> that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Note, if you change the script to:

```
(py38) 173-11-109-137-SFBA:~ juan$ cat test.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.__b = b
        print("Construct A")

    def __del__(self):
        # It seems that the destructor of B is called here.
        print("Delete A")
        # But it should be called here

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Construct B")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Delete B")
b = B()
a = A(b)

del a
del b
```

Then, executed:

```
(py38) 173-11-109-137-SFBA:~ juan$ python test.py
Construct B
Construct A
Delete A
Delete B
```

Although `del` does *not* delete objects, it deletes references, so it forces the reference count to reach 0 while the interpreter is still running, so the order is as you would expect.

Sometimes, `__del__` won't be called at all. A common circumstance is file-objects created by

```
f = open('test.txt')
```

That have live references in the global scope. If not closed explicitly,  it might not call `__del__` and the file will not flush and you won't get anything written. Which is a great reason to use the file object as a context-manager...

Answer (score 4):

Per the comments elsewhere on this question, you probably don't want to use `__del__`; it's not really a destructor in the C++ sense. You probably want to make the objects into context managers (by writing `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods) and use them in the `with` statement, and/or give them `close` methods which need to be called explicitly.

However, to answer the question as given: the reason is that both objects have references from the global variables `a` and `b`; neither reference count ever goes to zero. The destructor is called at the end when the python interpreter is shutting down and all the non-zero-count objects are being collected.

To see the behaviour you expect, put the `a` and `b` variables in a function so that the reference counts go to zero during the main part of execution.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.__b = b
        print("Construct A")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Delete A")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Construct B")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Delete B")

def foo():
    b = B()
    a = A(b)

foo()
```

Comment: I completely agree that context managers should be used instead of `__del__` and also your explanation of why the "incorrect" output is seen is clear. However, you might want to add a note that `__del__` is not a destructor but a finalizer (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__))

Comment: I suspect the distinction between a destructor and a finalizer won't help anyone who doesn't already know about it...

Comment: Well, if they see it as a destructor, the confusion is understandable. Like the comments in the code in the question demonstrate, OP expects the "destructor" of B to be called inside the "destructor" of A, which is similar to how this works in C++. However, a finalizer is called **after** an object is not referred to anymore, which explains why the order is the other way around. But it's your answer, feel free to add this or ignore it :-)

Comment: @wovano - partly added.

Answer (score 1):

Among the things you're missing, there's a reference cycle. It goes roughly `a->b->B->B.__init__->B.__init__.__globals__->a`:

- Your `A` instance has a reference to its `__dict__`, which has a reference to your `B` instance.
- Your `B` instance has a reference to your `B` class.
- Your `B` class has a reference to its `__dict__`, which has references to all of `B`'s methods. (Technically, if you try to access `B.__dict__` yourself, you'll get a mappingproxy wrapping `B`'s "real `__dict__`". `B` has a reference to the real dict, not the proxy.)
- `B`'s methods each have a reference to their global variable dict.
- The global variable dict has a reference to your `A` instance (because this dict is where the `a` global variable is).

When reclaiming objects in a reference cycle, there are no guarantees as to what order `__del__` methods are executed in.

If you don't believe the reference cycle exists, it's fairly straightforward to demonstrate the existence of these references:

```
import gc

print(a.__dict__ in gc.get_referents(a))
print(b in gc.get_referents(a.__dict__))
print(B in gc.get_referents(b))
# this bypasses the mappingproxy
# never use this to modify a class's dict - you'll cause memory corruption
real_dict = next(d for d in gc.get_referents(B) if isinstance(d, dict))
print(B.__init__ in gc.get_referents(real_dict))
print(B.__init__.__globals__ in gc.get_referents(B.__init__))
print(a in gc.get_referents(B.__init__.__globals__))
```

All of these `print`s print `True`.

---

Aside from that, there are a few relevant points other answers have already brought up. Your objects survive to interpreter shutdown, so there is no guarantee that `__del__` will be called at all. Also, `__del__` is a finalizer, not a destructor. It doesn't have anywhere near the same kind of guarantees that an actual destructor would have in a language like C++.

Comment: There's no reference from `B.__init__.__globals__` to `a`. Besides, when `a` is "deleted" (either by going out of function scope as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63097151/10669875) or by explicitly calling `del a` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63097174/10669875)), it will also be removed from the globals, so the reference cycle would be broken.

Comment: @wovano: There is a reference. It's the `a` global variable. `B.__init__.__globals__` is the module's global variable dict, which is where the `a` global variable lives. Also, `a` doesn't go out of scope (because it's not a function scope), and there is no `del a`.

Comment: @wovano: The part in your comment about "it will also be removed from the globals" suggests you might be misunderstanding some part of the Python variable semantics. Deleting a reference in some scope other than the globals won't delete a separate reference from the globals.

Comment: Can you prove your statement, or refer to (official) documentation explaining it? It doesn't make sense to me (because if it would be true, almost any object would have a circular reference, and the garbage collector couldn't do its job). And when I execute the code from the question followed by `dir(b.__init__.__globals__)`, it does not contain `a`. Accessing `b.__init__.__globals__.a` would give `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'`. So I don't see the cycle here...

Comment: @wovano: [Here's proof.](https://ideone.com/2Y4gug) Look at the `True` printed for `a in gc.get_referents(B.__init__.__globals__)`.

Comment: You're looking for attributes when you should be looking for references. A dict must hold references to all its keys and values, but those references are not attributes.

Comment: This doesn't cause circular references for most objects because most objects aren't reachable from global variables. When there is a circular reference, it doesn't stop the garbage collector from doing its job - handling circular references *is* the garbage collector's job.

Comment: @wovano: If that downvote is yours, I hope you remove it when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's not so trivial to reproduce that code. However, I'm still not sure why this is useful information or how it answers the question. Using your code I can also prove that there's a reference cycle from `a` to `a` and from `b` to `b`. But what's the point? How does this explain the behavior OP is seeing or what should be changed to the original question to avoid this "problem"? IMHO, it all boils down to "objects are still alive when the interpreter shuts down" which was already said. Sorry if I'm still missing something. To me this answer only adds more questions.

Comment: @wovano: "When reclaiming objects in a reference cycle, there are no guarantees as to what order `__del__` methods are executed in." The questioner expects `a.__del__` to execute first because `a` has a reference to `b`, but because there's a chain of references from `b` to `a`, there are no guarantees about which `__del__` goes first.

Comment: In something like sabik's code, where the reference cycle doesn't exist, `a`'s `__del__` goes first.

Answer (score -2):

This concept is called [composition](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3029325/exploring-association-aggregation-and-composition-in-oop.html):

> *In composition, if the parent object is destroyed, then the child objects also cease to exist. Composition is actually a strong type of aggregation and is sometimes referred to as a “death” relationship. As an example, a house may be composed of one or more rooms. If the house is destroyed, then all of the rooms that are part of the house are also destroyed.*

For an object to be *deleted*, all it's attributes need to be deleted **first**. From the above example, rooms of the house will be destroyed first in order for the house to be destroyed.

Therefore, `A` has an attribute of object `B` which will be deleted first.

Comment: I would expect that first `__del__`  is called and then the attributes should be destroyed (as it is in C++). A destructors usefulness is severely limited if I cannot use the attributes in it.

Comment: The meaningful use of `__del__` is pretty rare in Python. If you want to ensure that something is "finalized" at the end of some sort of "scope", consider instead using a context manager.

Comment: As @KarlKnechtel wrote, `__del__` is rarely useful in Python; as a practical example, if an exception is raised within a function, all local variables will be attached to that exception as part of the traceback. The variables will then remain alive and the `__del__` destructors will then not be called until later, possibly much later, when the exception is handled. In interactive use, the last unhandled exception traceback goes into `sys.last_traceback`, so the destructors won't be called until the _next_ unhandled exception.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak `__del__` is a "finalizer" not a destructor, like in C++. The python data object model is pretty different from C++, check out the [docs on `__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). As KarlKnetchtel wrote, you probably want a context manager

Comment: As proven by the [answer of sabik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63097151/10669875), this is not true. This is probably how you should implement constructors (for example in C++), but is not how `__del__` works in Python. Objects are deleted only when their reference count is 0, or possibly during the interpreter shutdown. In this example, `B` cannot be deleted as long as `A` is still alive, since `A` contains a reference to `B`.

Comment: "For an object to be deleted, all it's attributes need to be deleted first." The implication of this assertion is wrong. Since objects only hold *references to* their attribute values, it is sufficient to delete the reference, not the value. Specifically, this is important because several objects, such as ``None``, ``1``, ``2``, ..., ``True``, ``False``, are *never* destroyed during execution – any object holding them as any ancestor attribute could thus also never be destroyed if this answer were true.

Comment: Even in a language like C++, an object's members' destructors would execute *after* the "outer" object's destructor. The outer object's destructor needs its members to still be alive to be able to do anything with the object.